# Does Google bot create multiple index entries when query strings differ?

Tags: query-string, googlebot

If I have multiple hyper-references to the homepage within my website:

http://a.b.com/home?a=1

http://a.b.com/home?a=2

http://a.b.com/home?a=3

Is there a chance that Google search results will contain 3 cloned entries because of that difference in query-string?